# function trans doesn't work in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, localization

I'm trying to make language chooser in laravel with simple text changing, I have two php files `greetings` in language folders, one in english, one in german.

This code is in `de` folder:

```
return array(
  'hello' => 'Hallo'   
);
```

and this is in the `en` folder

```
return array(
  'hello' => 'Hello'   
);
```

And when I try to show the word in the view using function trans it gives me the code from the view, not the word.

```
{{ trans('greetings.hello') }}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage this by creating a middleware group.

```
//middleware
use Closure, Session;

class ManageLocalization {

protected $languages = ['en','de'];

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!Session::has('userLang'))
    {
        Session::put('userLang', $request->getPreferredLanguage($this->languages));
    }
    app()->setLocale(Session::get('userLang'));

    return $next($request);
}

}
```

add this to **kernel.php**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\ManageLocalization::class
    ],

protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'userLang' => \App\Http\Middleware\ManageLocalization::class
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change you locale in config/app.php like this :

'locale' => 'de',